# how to sort last 30 days to today in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

so, I want to make a filter based on last 30 days till now.

**code : **

```
dataTtransaction: { dataTransactionOrder: [ { "dateTransaction": "04-04-2023 08:53:14" }, { "dateTransaction": "30-05-2023 08:53:14" }, { "dateTransaction": "01-06-2023 08:53:14" }]}

filterDate(param) {

    let ends = new Date();
    let starts = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 30));
    let start = moment(starts).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
    let end = moment(ends).format('DD-MM-YYYY')

    this.prodFilter = this.dataTtransaction.dataTransactionOrder.filter( st => {
      let dates = moment(st.dateTransaction).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
      return (new Date(dates) >=  new Date(start) && new Date(dates) <= new Date(end))
    });
  }
```

so, I want to make a filter based on last 30 days till now

Comment: Use momentjs [isBetween](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/)

Comment: @AluanHaddad 
Previously I have used maybe I still don't understand
can you give an example?

Comment: [momentjs is dead](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze i have done that, but its not working